# Python and C# TcpListener - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, c#, sockets, tcp

I have a TCP listener written in C#. I have a Python script that reads a text file of about 500 JSON-formatted msgs and sends those msgs on port 8088 which the C# TCP listener picks up.

For some reason, whenever the Python scripts reaches message 202, I get the Python error:

```
Errno 10061
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

I've confirmed that there is nothing wrong with message 202 - I removed the first 100 messages from the text file and I get the same result on message 202. I'm not sure what exactly is going on. It seems like something is getting backed up or maybe some resources have reached their limit? Has anyone encountered a similar case before? This is what my C# TCP listener looks like:

```
public static async void StartTcpListener()
{
    TcpListener server = null;
    try
    {
        // Set the TcpListener on port 8088
        Int32 port = 8088;

        // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port)'
        server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);

        // Start listening for client requests
        server.Start();

        // Buffer for reading data
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[4096];
        String data = null;

        // Enter the listening loop.
        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient client = await server.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            if (client != null)
            {
                data = null;

                // Get a stream object for reading and writing
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                
                int i;

                if (stream.DataAvailable)
                {
                    // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
                    while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                        data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);

                        DecodeMessage(data);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(SocketException ex)
    {
        Log.Error("Error setting up TCP listener: ", ex.ToString());
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error("Exception: " + ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        server.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: The "actively refuse" message is due the code trying to open a new connection where a connection already exists with the same three properties 1) Source IP 2) Destination IP 3) Port number.  So you are leaving the method posted and then calling the method a 2nd time.  A listener can accept a connection from more than one client.  You do not need to start the listener for each client.  You can check status of the connection from cmd.exe >Netstat -a which will give a list of all TCP and UDP connections.

Comment: This method is only called once. The TcpListener server is only created once.

Comment: Where are you getting the exception?  There is nothing in your server/listener code that should give this exception except after you receive 100 messages unless the listener is called more than once.